# Connect AirPods that belongs to another Apple ID to shared Apple TV

Tags: bluetooth, appletv, airpods

I have an Apple TV. The main Apple account that is used to set-up the TV is mine. Without pairing my AirPods, it shows up on the TV when I want to use it while watching something.

Sometimes, someone in the house would use the TV and they have a different Apple ID than me. They have paired their AirPods to their phone. However I couldn't figure out how to have another AirPods that belongs to another Apple ID to connect to this TV.

What I've tried:

- Opened Settings app > Remotes and Devices > Bluetooth. The AirPods does not show up because it's already paired to someone's Apple ID.
- [Created a new account on the Apple TV](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/tv/atvb59ec8e2e/tvos) by going to Settings > Users & Accounts > Add new users. This is linked to the Airpods owner's Apple ID. The Airpods still does not show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the AirPods into pairing mode before they will show up in the Bluetooth devices list.

[Set up AirPods with your Mac and other Bluetooth devices (Apple)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208718):

> 3. Put both AirPods in the charging case and open the lid.
> 4. Press and hold the setup button on the back of the case until the status light flashes white.

Note: Do not hold the setup button longer than 15 seconds (at which point the light should flash amber before returning to white), or else the AirPods will [reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209463).

Comment: Wouldn't this unpair the airpods from the other person's phone though?

Comment: Nope. Unpairing is done explicitly in Bluetooth settings using “Forget this device”. Connecting to the Apple TV with a different Apple ID should function similar to connecting to a non-apple device, where the AirPods connect just like any other Bluetooth device.

Comment: Ah, got it thank you. So the automatic switching/pairing with Apple ID thing is not something that works on Apple TV. With iPad/Mac/iPhone I didn't have to pair the Airpod with each device separately.

Comment: TBH I’m not positive about Apple TV not supporting automatic switching with the same Apple ID. Some further clarification - you’re right that holding the button too long may “[reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209463)” the AirPods. In your case you wouldn’t want to hold it past the light turning white, as after 15 seconds it should flash amber and then back to white - which would be a “reset”.

Comment: It may depend on the account settings. For family sharing, manually pairing doesn’t seem necessary. We set up AirPods with ours, and aside from adding my wife’s account to the AppleTV I don’t recall having to pair the AirPods. Her AirPods show as available to connect even watching under my profile.